# Typo3 Multilingual

Tags: typo3, multilingual, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I want to do a Multilingual Version of my Extension. In case of this I completed the Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xliff version="1.0">
<file source-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2014-12-16T23:29:45Z" product-name="rere" target-language="en">
    <header/>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="tx_rere_domain_model_note">
            <source>Note</source>
            <target>Note</target>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="tx_rere_domain_model_note.notenr">
            <source>Notenr</source>
            <target>Notenr</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

It's a valid xml file.

Then I added in the html files this:

```
<f:translate key='tx_rere_domain_model_note'/>
```

But in the view there isn't shown anything ... als is blank

what's going wrong?

Comment: okay bug fixed now the lables were loaded

how can I swap between the languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to other languages you need to include a Navigation that lets you do just that. Language Menus are just a special type of navigation in Typo3.

Look up, what uids your languages are assignes to in the sys_language table - usually 0 is the default, and every language you add gets an entry with a uid incremented by one - so, given 0: english, 1: german, the most basic configuration would look like this:

```
lib.languages = HMENU
lib.languages {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,1
}
```

It's explained more thoroughly in the reference:

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#hmenu-special-property

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: So, you haven't localized your content yet? Thats a bit harder to explain in just text, you probably find a better tutorial for that on youtube. Basically you got to switch to the language view mode in the pages module. This will get you seperate views for all the languages you've set up. You can then duplicate content from the default language and localize it.

Comment: what do you men with localized the content? I've set up the locallang.xlf and in all views the ' <f:translate tag' 

but now i want to test the other language (in backend)

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought you were talking about content on the page. What do you mean with backend? Is the Extension a Backend plugin? Then you'll just have to set the language of the user to something else. If you have a Frontend plugin, you need to switch to the language with the menu I've posted.

Comment: the extension has got a backend and a frontend plug in. 

okay the I try to change the language of the backend user

Comment: So i've tried it. I changed my User from German to English. Cleared the Cache but nothing changed. only the german version is displayed.

in my locallang.xlf I have source="de" and target="en" '<file source-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2014-12-16T23:29:45Z" product-name="rere" target-language="en">'

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extension key. You don't need it as long as your view is inside the same extension. Try this:

```
<trans-unit id="note">
    <source>Note</source>
    <target>Note</target>
</trans-unit>

<f:translate key='note'/>
```

Comment: thanks the view works fine now. 

But how can I swap the language zu see the result?